# Visual Studio for Mac .NET Core 1.1.0 Nuget fails to install

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

So I've installed Visual Studio for Mac and running Sierra 10.12.1. There is an issue with installing certain Nugets and whilst resolving `Microsoft.AspNet.Core.Mvc` issue (which was due to TargetFramework in project file wasn't 1.1.0) I'm struggling with `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`.

Here is the error message

```
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 1.1.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 1.1.0' to App
Build started 11/24/2016 10:44:38 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/Users/joakimcarselind/Projects/Cure/Cure/src/App/App.csproj" (restore target(s)):

Target _GenerateRestoreGraph:
    __________________________________________________
    Project "/Users/joakimcarselind/Projects/Cure/Cure/src/App/App.csproj" is building "/Users/joakimcarselind/Projects/Cure/Cure/src/App/App.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry target(s)):

    Target _GenerateRestoreDependencies:
        __________________________________________________
        Project "/Users/joakimcarselind/Projects/Cure/Cure/src/App/App.csproj" is building "/Users/joakimcarselind/Projects/Cure/Cure/src/App/App.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreGraphWalkPerFramework target(s)):


    Target _GetAllRestoreProjectReferences:
        __________________________________________________
        Project "/Users/joakimcarselind/Projects/Cure/Cure/src/App/App.csproj" is building "/Users/joakimcarselind/Projects/Cure/Cure/src/App/App.csproj" (_GenerateRestoreProjectReferencePaths target(s)):

Target Restore:
    Restoring packages for /Users/joakimcarselind/Projects/Cure/Cure/src/App/App.csproj...

      CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/index.json
      GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg
      OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg 48ms
    Failed to download package from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg'.
    Failure has occurred while loading a type.
      GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg
      OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg 4ms
    Failed to download package from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg'.
    Failure has occurred while loading a type.
      GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg
      OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg 6ms
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/NuGet.targets : error : Failed to download package from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/NuGet.targets : error : Failure has occurred while loading a type.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/NuGet.targets(70,5): error MSB4018: The "RestoreTask" task failed unexpectedly.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/NuGet.targets(70,5): error MSB4018: This is an unhandled exception from a task -- PLEASE OPEN A BUG AGAINST THE TASK OWNER.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/NuGet.targets(70,5): error MSB4018: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load package 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions'.

 ... lots of text (couldn't fit it all since it was >150' lines
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.0/lib/mono/xbuild/NuGet.targets(70,5): error MSB4018: 
    0 Warning(s)
    2 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.52

Install failed. Rolling back...
Executing nuget actions took 3.65 sec
Failed to download package from 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions/1.1.0/microsoft.extensions.configuration.fileextensions.1.1.0.nupkg'.
Failure has occurred while loading a type.
```

If someone at Microsoft sees this here are some other concerns :)

- Overall experience with searching after Nuget packages is horrible. One would like to be able to search using wildcards or, at least, expect it to find related packages if just entering Json (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json is not found...).
- Also reporting a problem from VS isn't working, it complains over internet connection which I have since I'm posting this question from the same computer.

Comment: its rather unclear what youre asking, you seem to have several issues all relating to VS being on the mac, no internet connection and nuget not working as you would like

Comment: I edited the question so that the actual question (hopefully) is clear. Internet connectivity is obviously not an issue since I was able to post this question (which perhaps isn't all that obvious since I could have switched computer :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the dependency `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions` first and then adding `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` resulted in a successful install!

Edit: The happy times was unfortunately over sooner then i'd hoped. Exact same issue when trying to install EntityFrameworkCore and the list of transient dependencies are hopeless to follow bortom up

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I just went to manage NuGet Packages and Update the packages to the latest. That works for me.